# When was the geological timescale determined by radiometric dating?

Tags: nuclear-physics, geology

Long before radiometric dating, Earth's history was divided into a timescale with named units based on bands of rocks and fossils. Thus events could be placed in order by superposition. Some time later, we were able to be more quantitative, e.g. stating that the Cretaceous began 145 mya. When were these dates computed and accepted?

Comment: Isn't this straightforward to look up on WP?

Comment: @BenCrowell I tried, but only found a timeline of research on the age of Earth, which doesn't even say when the Hadean ended, let alone when (say) the Devonian began.